# How to recover after malicious code removal?

Tags: googlebot, bingbot

I just removed some malicious code from one of my client's website's theme. It was a result of a pirated theme the client was using and had ignored some hidden code with hyperlinks to betting sites.

According to my knowledge I can not do much but to wait for the pages to be crawled again and the change be noticed. Am I right with this assumption or is there any action that webmasters can take in this kind of situations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you are right. I would say that if Google and/or Bind are paying attention to the site, it would be better to just wait. First it would take time to spider the entire site, then it would take time to refresh the index and even more time to correct any penalty that may be applied. Expect as much as 60 days before the SERPs trend toward any correction. I can take more time after that (months depending) for the SERPs to settle in.

It has been my experience that you cannot speed up the search engines except for a few things I noticed in Google.

If they have a Google Webmasters Tool account and their site is validated, submit a fresh sitemap and seek to create Google Search code. Complete these steps in this exact order and complete these steps as if this is what you want. You will not have to deploy the Google Search code to the site. Because of the Google Search and sitemap submission, Google will try and spider the entire site immediately and fast. This may help speed things up.

Other than that, nothing else comes to mind.